# Why {}.toString can check data type?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain a bit about why these codes can check data type? They does not make sense to me. I cannot understand what the codes do behind the scene. Thanks in advance!

```
var toClass = {}.toString // {} is for what? toString is a method?

alert(toClass); // alert it I get a function? = > function toString() {[native code]}

alert( toClass.call( [1,2] ) )  
alert( toClass.call( new Date ) )
```

Comment: 'cos it is designed this way and implemented by the JS engines? This is like asking, why is the earth round? Because it is created that way. Voting to close as non-constructive.

Comment: Yes, [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var toClass = {}.toString;
```

is equivalent to

```
var toClass = Object.prototype.toString;
```

because

```
{}
```

*as an expression* (`Object` initialiser) is equivalent to

```
new Object()
```

where `Object` is “the standard built-in constructor with that name” ([ECMAScript Language Specification, 5.1 Edition, section 11.1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5); and earlier Editions).

So `{}` stands in for a reference to a new `Object` instance.  `Object` instances by default inherit properties from the object initially referred to by `Object.prototype` through the prototype chain ([section 15.2.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.5)), including the built-in property `Object.prototype.toString`. The property value is initially a reference to a `Function` instance, i.e. the property is a method that you can call ([section 15.2.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2)).

`alert` is actually `window.alert` (and should be written so).  `window` is a property of the ECMAScript global object; the object referred to by that property is a host object in the scope chain which has the `alert` method. Neither of those is specified in ECMAScript, but they are [provided by some host environments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert) (usually by browsers) as allowed by the Specification ([section 15.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1)).

Because it is designed to display alert messages, the `alert` host method displays the *string representation* of its first argument.  For objects, that includes calling their `toString` or `valueOf` method, whichever is supported first ([section 9.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)). `Function` instances, such as that referred to by `{}.toString`, inherit themselves a `toString` method that returns the implementation-dependent representation of the function ([section 15.3.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2)).

There are no classes, though, and the ECMAScript concept of `[[Class]]` is somewhat different from that of "data type" (see `typeof` and `instanceof`). These are languages using *prototype-based* inheritance ([section 4.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1)).

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call([1, 2]);
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date);
```

Here, `Object.prototype.toString` is the default `toString` method that all objects inherit by default. When invoked it prints something like this:

```
[object XXX]
```

*`{}.toString` is similar here, because `{}` is short for `new Object()`.*

Derived objects are free to override the `toString` method to suit their needs, for example:

```
> [1, 2].toString()
"1,2"

> (new Date).toString()
"Wed Feb 27 2013 17:03:42 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)"
```

However, you can still use the "primitive" method by using `.call()` on either `Object.prototype.toString` or `{}.toString` whereby the first parameter to `.call()` is used to define what `this` refers to inside the method you're calling.

Comment: You notion of "traditional OOP" is wrong, both on the distinction and the implementation. It would work in *class-based* OOP exactly the same way, only that the object would inherit from a class instead of from a prototype object.

Comment: @PointedEars Fine, removed the OOP reference. It wasn't really necessary anyway.

Comment: It was one of the reasons, but your edited version is sufficiently correct for me to revert the vote.

Comment: @PointedEars Much obliged :)